# What is the big-O complexity of this code

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

Whats the big-O notation of this code?

```
for( int i=1; i<2n; i++)
   x=x+1;
```

My answer = `O(2*n)` Is this correct?

Comment: That code won't run. `2n` is not valid Java code.

Comment: I think the java tag is not relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is O(n).  Big O is meant to describe the complexity of the application and in this case it is linear so it is O(n).

Answer (score 3):

*Consider this an `A` algorithm*

```
for( int i=1; i<2*n; i++)
 x=x+1;
```

Algorithm A’s run-time: `T(n) = 2n-1`

1. Eliminate lower-order terms: `2n-1 -> 2n`
2. Drop all constant coefficients: `2n -> n`

So the algorithm A’s time complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: this makes for a better answer with the explantion

Comment: @MChaker, what if the second line become k=1+1, is it O(1) now?

Comment: No it still O(n) @olala

Answer (score 0):

The big-o run time of this is O(2n) like you guessed but that is usually just simplified to O(n).